# design ROM to save filter coefficients in verilog

Tags: verilog, rom

I want to store filter coefficients(fixed values) in ROM using verilog.Below is the code for ROM using case.

---

```
module rom_using_case (
address , // Address input
data    , // Data output
read_en , // Read Enable 
ce        // Chip Enable
);
input [3:0] address;
output [7:0] data;
input read_en;
input ce;

reg [7:0] data ;

always @ (ce or read_en or address)
begin
  case (address)
    0 : data = 10;
    1 : data = 55;
    2 : data = 244;
    3 : data = 0;
    4 : data = 1;
    5 : data = 8'hff;
    6 : data = 8'h11;
    7 : data = 8'h1;
    8 : data = 8'h10;
    9 : data = 8'h0;
    10 : data = 8'h10;
    11 : data = 8'h15;
    12 : data = 8'h60;
    13 : data = 8'h90;
    14 : data = 8'h70;
    15 : data = 8'h90;
  endcase
end

endmodule
```

---

what does the case block do in the above code?
can i store filter coefficients in data variable in the case block?
can i access those filter coefficients?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you state the coefficients will be stored in a RAM LUT or in a ROM block.
The code is (somewhat) self-descriptive, the `always`  is sensitive to the `address` then each time the address changes its value the stored value will be assigned to `data`, `case` is the selector for which location of the memory block will be assinged to data.

Your implementation is enough for small filters, but if you need a lot of coefficients it will get hard to maintain.

For this purpose you can use the `$readmemh` or `$readmemb`. Those are verilog intrisic [tasks](http://verilog.renerta.com/mobile/source/vrg00016.htm).

From: https://www.csee.umbc.edu/~tinoosh/cmpe415/slides/Rom-LUT-verilog.pdf

The `$readmemh` system task expects the content of the named file to be
a sequence of hexadecimal numbers, separated by spaces or line breaks.
Similarly, `$readmemb` expects the file to contain a sequence of binary.

Here is a snippet which shows how to use it:

```
reg [19:0] data_ROM [0:511];
...
initial $readmemh("rom.data", data_ROM); 
always @(address)
  if (ce & read_en)
    d_out = data_ROM[address];
```

The `"rom.data"` contains the coefficients in text. For example, in your case:

```
8'hA
8'h37
8'hF4
8'h0
8'h1
8'hff
8'h11
8'h1
8'h10
8'h0
8'h10
8'h15
8'h60
8'h90
8'h70
8'h90
```

Comment: (1)does the 8 in 8'h1 represent 8-bit number?(2)can i save signed double values like 0.0389 and -0.0181 in rom by any method?

Comment: (1) Yes, it represents 8 bit number in hex representation. (2) You can store them in hex. But the fpga wont recognize them as double in 0.038 format, but as 64h'3d1f559b which is the binary representation. Remember that double is in IEEE754 encoding. Here you can convert them: https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html